# Using Google places API in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-places-api

I am working on a `chrome extension` that makes use of the Google places `API`. I am not able to load the API due to `Content Security` Policy(https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy). I tried using permissions, get request, adding the script to body on document ready (what I found on research), nothing works. I get this error all the time:

```
Refused to load the script 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY8&sensor=true&callback=initialize' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://apis.google.com".
```

Is it so that one cannot make a chrome extension using a `Google API` or may be any other external `API`? Can someone suggest some way to do so.

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2, 
  "version": "1.0", 
  "permissions": [ 
    "identity", 
    "https://*.google.com/", 
    "geolocation", 
    "maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/…; ], 
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' maps.googleapis.com object-src 'self'" 
}
```

Comment: Did you try adding `https://maps.googleapis.com` to your CSP?

Comment: yes i did...still does not work...you want me to add my manifest file code here?

Comment: {"manifest_version": 2,
    "version": "1.0",
    "permissions": [
        "identity",
        "https://*.google.com/",
        "geolocation",
        "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB7q8YoxtrcJyRTdTZ-aATgMbBYqZtDIe8&sensor=true"
    ],
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://maps.googleapis.com/ object-src 'self'"
}

Comment: CSP should have `https://maps.googleapis.com` in it not `maps.googleapis.com`.

Comment: Can the original poster edit the question to include full manifest.json? And @abraham, why did you edit the question to include a MALFORMED file that the original poster did NOT provide?

Comment: @Xan the malformed manifest was provided by the OP. Just in an impossible to read comment instead of nicely formatted.

Comment: @MridulaTripathi also your permissions should include the `https://` before `maps.googleapis.com...` and it looks like the CSP error lists a domain not allowed in your custom CSP.